# Recreate a flattened tree

Tags: recursion, clojure, tree, nested, zipper

I have a vector of maps, that I'd like to transform in a nested fashion.

The data is structured as follows:

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :name "a" :parent 0}
   {:id 2 :name "b" :parent 0}
   {:id 3 :name "c" :parent 0}
   {:id 4 :name "a_1" :parent 1}
   {:id 5 :name "a_2" :parent 1}
   {:id 6 :name "b_1" :parent 2}
   {:id 7 :name "a_1_1" :parent 4}])
```

Each map has an `:id`, some other keys and values not important for this discussion, and `:parent` key, denoting if the elements belong to another element. If `:parent` is 0, it's a top level element.

I want to nest this flattened list so that each element belonging to a parent gets stored under a key `:nodes` in the parent map, like this:

```
(def nested
  [{:id 1 :name "a" :parent 0 :nodes
    [{:id 4 :name "a_1" :parent 1 :nodes []}
     {:id 5 :name "a_2" :parent 1 :nodes
      [{:id 7 :name "a_1_1" :parent 4 :nodes []}]}]}
   {:id 2 :name "b" :parent 0 :nodes
    [{:id 6 :name "b_1" :parent 2}]}
   {:id 3 :name "c" :parent 0 :nodes []}])
```

To sum up - I have a flattened tree-like structure that I whish to transform into a tree again. I tried to achieve this using zippers, but failed to handle arbritarily nested levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to build it recursively by performing a full scan at each step:

```
(defn tree
  ([flat-nodes]
    (tree flat-nodes 0))
  ([flat-nodes parent-id]
    (for [node flat-nodes
          :when (= (:parent node) parent-id)]
      (assoc node
        :nodes (tree flat-nodes (:id node))))))
```

and then

```
=> (tree data)
({:parent 0, :name "a", :nodes 
   ({:parent 1, :name "a_1", :nodes 
     ({:parent 4, :name "a_1_1", :nodes (), :id 7}), :id 4}
    {:parent 1, :name "a_2", :nodes (), :id 5}), :id 1}
 {:parent 0, :name "b", :nodes
   ({:parent 2, :name "b_1", :nodes (), :id 6}), :id 2}
 {:parent 0, :name "c", :nodes (), :id 3})
```

## Update: A more efficient variation

```
(defn tree [flat-nodes]
  (let [children (group-by :parent flat-nodes)
        nodes (fn nodes [parent-id]
                (map #(assoc % :nodes (nodes (:id %)))
                  (children parent-id)))]
    (nodes 0)))
```

Comment: While maybe not the most performant solution this is definitely the cleanest and most intuitively understandable. And unless the tree in question is really large it'll be perfectly fine. Colour me amazed.

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution! Seems so obious now that I look at it, but I would never have come up with this myself.

Comment: good solution. but this is not a tail recursion so the concern is if it's a big tree, StackOverflow error may happen?

Answer (score 1):

Such a tree has to be built from the bottom up, so we need a function that will split a seq of nodes into leaves and inner ones:

```
(defn split-leaves
  [nodes]
  (let [parent-id? (set (map :parent nodes))]
    (group-by
      (comp #(if % :inner :leaves) parent-id? :id)
      nodes)))
```

The next step is attaching all leaves to their parents:

```
(defn attach-leaves
  [inner leaves]
  (let [leaves-by-parent (group-by :parent leaves)]
    (map
      (fn [{:keys [id] :as node}]
        (update-in node [:nodes] concat (leaves-by-parent id)))
      inner)))
```

Those two steps have to be repeated until there are only leaves left:

```
(defn generate
  [nodes root-id]
  (loop [nodes (conj nodes {:id root-id})]
    (let [{:keys [leaves inner]} (split-leaves nodes)]
      (if (seq inner)
        (recur (attach-leaves inner leaves))
        (some #(when (= (:id %) root-id) (:nodes %)) leaves)))))
```

Note that we have to add and remove a virtual root node for this to work since your original set of nodes did not contain one (that's why the function expects the root node's ID).

```
(generate data 0)
;; => ({:parent 0, :name "c", :id 3}
;;     {:parent 0, :name "b",
;;      :nodes ({:parent 2, :name "b_1", :id 6}),
;;      :id 2}
;;     {:parent 0, :name "a",
;;      :nodes ({:parent 1, :name "a_2", :id 5}
;;              {:parent 1, :name "a_1",
;;               :nodes ({:parent 4, :name "a_1_1", :id 7}),
;;               :id 4}),
;;      :id 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert your child parent relationships to an adjacency list and then traverse the acyclic directed graph.

```
(defn adjacency-list [coll]
  (reduce (fn [r {p :parent c :id}]
            (-> r
              (update-in [:counts p] #(or % 0))
              (update-in [:counts c] #(if % (inc %) 1))
              (update-in [:adjacency p] #(if % (conj % c) [c]))))
          {}
          coll))

(defn get-data [k]
  (first (filter #(= (:id %) k) data)) )

(defn traverse [m al roots]
  (reduce (fn [r k]
            (conj r
                  (assoc (get-data k)
                         :nodes (if-let [v (get al k)]
                                  (traverse [] al v)
                                  []))))
          m
          roots))

(clojure.pprint/pprint
 (let [{:keys [adjacency]} (adjacency-list data)]
   (traverse [] adjacency (get adjacency 0))))
```